# Count bits in VBScript

Tags: bitwise, vbscript

I'm trying to write a function that returns the number of bits set in a 32-bit integer in VBScript, it's just for practising the language. The function I've written so far looks okay, but I'm wondering if there was a simpler solution.

```
Function countBits(value)
  Dim n : n = 0
  Dim mask : mask = 1
  Dim i
  For i = 0 to 30
    If (value And mask) > 0 Then
      n = n +1
    End If
  Next
  If (value And &h8000) then
    n = n+1
  End If
  countBits = n
End Function
```

I found that there are no shift operators in VBScript and an overflow (`Err.Number = 6`) if I iterate for 0 to 31, that's why I add the explicitly check of the MSB after the look.

Any solutions to improve (maybe generalize) this?

---

edit: removed the useless error handling part, as it's a remains of starting with 31 as an upper bound in the first (and at that time only) loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to information in [VBScript Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx) MSDN article, a 32-bit integer is `long` variant subtype.

However, the value `&h8000` (decimal  `-32768`) seems to be a 16-bit **`integer` minimal value**; it's hexadecimal `&hFFFF8000` if converted to `long` subtype (check `Wscript.Echo Hex(&h8000)`.

This means that your function **miscounts** 1 additional bit for all `long` values above `32767` i.e. **above** 16-bit **`integer` maximal value** `&h7FFF`.

To check the sign bit of a `long` value correctly, use `&h80000000` as follows:

```
Function countBits(value)
  Dim mask : mask = 1
  Dim i
  countBits = 0                    ' no need to use any auxiliary variable
  For i = 0 to 30
    If ( value And mask ) > 0 Then
      countBits = countBits + 1
    End If
    mask = mask * 2                ' got lost due to your own edit Dec 11 '16 at 14:22
  Next
  If ( value And &h80000000 ) Then ' check the sign bit
    countBits = countBits + 1
  End If
End Function
```

Sample tests:

```
Wscript.Echo countBits(2^16)         '  1
Wscript.Echo countBits(2^30)         '  1
Wscript.Echo countBits(1)            '  1
Wscript.Echo countBits(-1)           ' 32
Wscript.Echo countBits(-2)           ' 31
Wscript.Echo countBits(-2147483648)  '  1
```

Comment: thanks so much sometimes I seem to be so blind for some important details, the **off-by-one syndrome has so many faces** this time I was off by one chunk of hexadecimal places.